# how to get sundays in given period

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<script>
var startDate = "2023/04/01";
var endDate = "2023/04/16";
var dateMove = new Date(startDate);
var strDate = startDate;    
while (strDate < endDate){
    var strDate = dateMove.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    array.push(strDate);
    dateMove.setDate(dateMove.getDate()+1);         
};
$('.show').html(array);
</script>
result"2023/04/01","2023/04/01","2023/04/02","2023/04/03","2023/04/04","2023/04/05","2023/04/06","2023/04/07","2023/04/08","2023/04/09","2023/04/10","2023/04/11","2023/04/12","2023/04/13","2023/04/14","2023/04/15","2023/04/16"
```

how to get results on Sundays `2023/04/02`,`2023/04/09`,`2023/04/16`

Answer (score 2):

Study the following code and look up the functions that it uses in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) of the `Date` object.

```js
var array = [];
for (var d = new Date("2023-04-01");
  d <= new Date("2023-04-16");
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1))
  if (d.getUTCDay() === 0)
    array.push(d.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
document.body.textContent = array;
```

Comment: thank's you so much

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the first Sunday from the start date, then loop while adding `7` to the date each time. (There is no need to go through every single day in the range just to find Sundays.)

```js
let startDate = "2023/04/01";
let endDate = "2023/04/16";
let curr = new Date(startDate), end = new Date(endDate);
curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + (7 - curr.getDay()) % 7);
let res = [];
for (; curr <= end; curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 7)) 
  res.push(curr.toLocaleDateString('en-ZA'));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following. 1. Set the start and end dates. 2. Loop through each day from the start date to the end date. 3. Check if the current day is a Sunday (Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc.) and push it to the sudays array. Important - you should increase currentDate in the loop.

```js
    const startDate = new Date("2023/04/01");
    const endDate = new Date("2023/04/16");

    let currentDate = startDate;
    let sundays = [];
    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
      if (currentDate.getDay() === 0) {
        sundays.push(currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-ZA'));
      }
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    console.log(sundays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const startDate = new Date('2023/04/01')
const endDate = new Date('2023/04/16')
const sundays = []

for (let d = startDate; d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1))
  !d.getDay() && sundays.push(new Date(d).toLocaleDateString('en-ZA'))

console.log(sundays)
```

Comment: Date arithmetic with milliseconds does not work quite right if daylight saving time is involved.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen thank you for your comment.. Code refactored